# looking for a solution in client cache

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

We provide a map in the web page(just like the google map),when user zoom in/out,move the map,we need to make a request to the server to get some information , so the request event will be so frequent,it will slow down the speed of user's acton,for example,when user move the map, he/she will notice it is not smooth enougth,so I wonder if there is some out -of -box sloution of client cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends how your Map is implemented. Is this images you want to cache?  If they are the result of http requests, then if your content can be cached and has a suitable expiry time the browser cache will prevent duplicate requests for the same content.

Alternatively or as well as you could take advantage of HTML5 local storage, but if it's image data you are caching you'll have to convert it to base64 ascii, as the local storage only allows text data in as the value.

Comment: absolutely not the image, The image will be cached by the browser itself,isn't it?  We request some addentional information which will be returned by xml/json format..

Comment: @hguser they will be cached if the http headers say they can be.  You might want to check this out with a profiler and see - e.g. you may be getting a lot of unnecessary 304 Not Modified requests if the browser is checking for updates.  If it's safe for the client to cache the images for a longer time set a fairly long expiry time on them, so the browser won't make any request.  If it's just text data either cache in a JavaScript data structure for the lifetime of the DOM or as @orip states store using browser capabilities, maybe through a framework like PersistJS (which will stay longer)

Comment: Thanks I will have a try with presistjs. But it seems that this framwork is not very active,I wonder if there is any other likely framwork?

Comment: +1, having the correct HTTP response headers will have the browser cache the XML/JSON responses as well, the date URLs just need to be unique

Comment: the xml/json is not static,they are generated in the serverside according the map's current loaction and level.for exmaple:http://mysite/WebService.asmx?boundbox=-122,24,-119,26&level=3  You can try the google map,and open the firebut,try move the map or zoom in/out,you will find that google request something each time, Since we do not have the powerful server like google,so we  can make the request each time,then we thougth the cache in client.\

Answer (score 1):

[PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to combine many techniques to create a smoother experience for your users.

A few ideas:

- Pre-fetch images with javascript ([Example](http://www.4thkingdom.com/public/computers/789073-web-site-speed-prefetching-images-css/view-post.html))
- Use image maps or CSS sprites to reduce the number of requests you make to the server
- Tweak the headers of your images to optimize the way the browser keeps them in cache
- Store you images in different domains to speed up the download time using parallel domains ([Example](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/))
- Reduce the size of your images with better compression algorithms

Storing images on the user's machine is not a good idea.